# Exclude folder under dynamic links in Installshield

Tags: file, installshield, dynamic-linking

Is there a way to exclude a folder that is located under a dynamic link in InstallShield?

So I have a dynamic link that starts at  PATH A, and the following is a small example directory structure:

```
PATH A
  --- PATH B
        --- PATH C (which contains files)
        --- PATH D (which contains files)

  --- PATH E (which contains files)

  --- PATH F
        --- PATH G (which contains files)
```

Currently I have a dynamic link that starts at PATH A, includes sub directories, and uses a *.* wild card with some explicit file exclusions.

What I want to do now is to completely exclude a directory, for example completely exclude PATH F from the above example directory structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [no](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=149213) - [way](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?p=442094).

I've been trying to do this since InstallShield 6.  They're at InstallShield 15 now, and you still can't do it.  If you use Subversion and are concerned about about .svn directories, you could solve the problem the way I did:  have your build process do an `svn export` to an intermediate directory before building.

Comment: Thanks William. This is quite the inconvenience, it would certainly be nice if they fixed it.... since adding dynamic links to each sub directory explicitly is not going to be pleasant.